# Wordpress and custom css/js include with php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem that is driving me mad!

I made a custom website in which I decided to include a wordpress blog. I've installed wp in a separated directory (**www.mywebsite.com/blog**) and I have customized the wp theme with a child theme to include the same header and footer of my website, along with my own css and js. It all works flawlessly when I'm in the main directory of my blog, but when I open a post, for example, the url changes and it messes up all the paths that links to my custom css and js.

The file I'm trying to include is stored in **mywebsite.com/common** and it contains all the links to the css and js documents, which are stored in **mywebsite.com/css** and **mywebsite.com/js**.

This is what I did to make it work in the main **mywebsite.com/blog** directory, so how can I adapt it to make it work dynamically when the url changes?

```
<?php include "../common/fonts-css-js.php"; ?>
```

NOTE: I have also tried writing a small function to "count" how many sub-directories the viewed page was in, but it doesn't really work...

```
function dynamicPath()
{
  $levels = substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"/");
  for ($i=0; $i < $levels - 1; $i++)
  {
    $path.= "../";
  }
  return $path;
}
<?php include "{$path}common/fonts-css-js.php"; ?>
```

How can I prevent the url changes?

Comment: Usually with wordpress, url related problems are solved by disabling permalinks or at least regenerating them. http://sangkrit.net/how-to-regenerate-permalinks-based-on-post-titles-in-wordpress/

Comment: Just use relative paths beginning with a `/` for your JS and CSS resources, so that the refer to the domain root. Then it doesn’t matter how many “subfolders” deep the document that embeds them is.